# What do mobile-web apps use instead of LocalStorage when they go native?

Tags: android, ios, html, local-storage

Just like the title. This seems to be an easy question but I'm not very familiar with native development so I would like to get an explanation.

My question is:

> Web apps (including mobile web app, which has mobile-friendly UI&UX, which can use popular frameworks such as Sencha Touch, jQuery Mobile, etc.) have the ability to "go offline" with LocalStorage. This can be simply understood as a "persistent database" of the browser. So when they go native (I mean packaging them into a native app), does the LocalStorage still exist and work? If yes, are they still LocalStorage or will they be "transformed" into another native kind of storage with equal functionalities?

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: Note: I welcome criticism but feel very unpleasant with anonymous downvoting. Please give me a reason, a duplicate or something like that. I did search and read before asking this question.

Comment: Local storage is not a relevant concept when dealing with native applications.  It simply becomes "storage."

Comment: @borrden It's not what he was asking.

Comment: By "native" do you mean fully Java/Objective-C (and similar) rewrite? Or do you mean wrapping an HTML (+JS+CSS) webapp in a web view of some sort, akin to what Cordova/PhoneGap does, and deploying that via the market? Seems there's a touch of confusion about exactly which you're referring to.

Comment: @ Kitsune: thank you, I mean the 2nd one. Wrapping in into a native webview. I just wonder whether LocalStorage still persists, or it becomse another kind of native storage..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They (Android from my own experience and iOS from reading about) are not using anything instead - they are using the same local storage!

It's being done by telling the native WebView/webkit that is running the page to map all the local storage to some path on device persistent storage. It's very simple to implement. 
Pay attention that using the Android persistent data will require you to ask user permission for writing data to disk.

From the HTML developer point of view there's nothing special that needs to be done.